# Use of choke to create analog ground: mistake?

Tags: inductor, grounding

Not infrequently I see designs that implement an analog ground like in the following schematic:

[image]

This is a breakout module that includes an electret microphone module and amplifier that could feed into the A/D converter of an arduino or similar. (It's Adafruit 1063, not to pick on them particularly, just an example).

The feature of interest is the choke FB1 in the ground line to create a separate "AGnd" Analog ground. I think the intent might be to run the Max4466 amplifier on a clean ground, separate from the noisy digital ground.

Now, it's certainly a good idea to separate AVCC from VCC with a choke, (as is done here with FB2), and bypass it with a cap to ground (not done here).

However, the choke in the ground conductor is a problem. The microphone and amp inputs are referenced to AVCC, but the amp output is referenced to the external ground. The consequence surely must be that half the noise on (external) VCC (JP1 pin 1) appears at the analog output (JP1-pin 3).

And indeed, this circuit produces very noisy output, when used, for example, with an Arduino and an SD card module as a sound recorder. (SD cards are latter notorious for VCC noise while writing.) This is greatly improved by replacing FB1 with a short, and adding better filtering in place of FB2.

My question:

In general, is there ever an argument in favor of putting chokes in the ground network to create ground branches that have some high-frequency isolation? My inclination is that grounds should always be as low-impedance as possible, with due regard to current flow issues, return paths etc to avoid unwanted voltage drops (star ground considerations etc), and *not* deliberately partitioned with chokes. But I've seen the addition of chokes to ground branches enough to wonder whether there is some argument in favor.

Comment: Keep in mind that noise on the *amplified output* is less of an issue than noise on the *input*.  What might be better still is to bring out a differential reference.  You also have to consider the supply situation of the ADC, eg, it often has a similar arrangement.  Recording audio to an SD card with an Arduino's ADC is a fairly low quality idea to begin with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree with your comments on this specific example, however (a) it's just an example, (b) by "Arduino" I mean to include family members that are faster and have higher-res ADCs than Uno R3. Extending your point though, where the (stand-alone) ADC has a "similar arrangement", perhaps you mean that the ADC has its Ground (or AGnd) attached to system ground via a choke. In which case I'd suspect we would want that choked ground directly connected to the ground of the input stage that feeds it, for least noisy ADC input signal.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that you'd reference all of the analog stuff to the analog ground.  This board can't do that since it's connectorized.   You're free to try shunting the ferrites and see if performance changes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As mentioned in my post "This is greatly improved by replacing FB1 with a short, and adding better filtering in place of FB2."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's old practice.

PCB paritioning does not mean what you think it means. Partitioning means to separate components to different regions of the same single continuous ground plane so return currents of a noisy section don't flow under a sensitive section. Partioning components is better than splitting the ground plane (which is what your schematic is doing is called). It's really easy to make things worse by splitting than if you just did nothing in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. (a) What is the rationale for that "old practice". (b) I'm not sure what PCB ground plane partitioning has to do with the topic at hand, which is: what might be the effect of placing an inductor in a ground net to partition it off from a/the main ground net. Yes, they both involve the words "ground" and "partition", but to discuss two different practices, each with its own rationales. At least, I imagine the choked ground net has a rationale -- that's what I'm hoping to discover here!

Comment: @gwideman No, both practices do not involve the word partitioning. You posted about one splitting but called it partitioning when that means something else. In this topic area, the word "partition" means something more specific than the general use. That is the reason I brought up partitioning to begin with.

Comment: @gwideman The rationale is that it allows DC return currents to pass through to keep the DC potential of both planes balanced, but prevents high frequency noise return currents from contaminating the planes. But it doesn't work and we haven't always understood PCBs as well as we do now (nor have we always built circuits where you could not get away with such practice).

Comment: I appreciate you weighing in with the opinion that these ground chokes don't work, that's at least a vote in favor of my observations. As to "partitioning", I infer you are steeped in practice that uses "partitioning" to refer only to partitioning of a PCB component placement or power plane. Where "partitioning" is reserved for that use, what would you call the separation of the ground net into separate "parts"? ("Isolation" is obviously not appropriate, as that refers to completely disconnected circuitry.)

Comment: @gwideman Yes. If you had not provided a schematic and said the ground plane was partitioned people would interpret it differently than the schematic you posted. Actual separation of ground nets is called splitting the planes, which includes the practice of having a physical divide in the plane, regardless of whether the bridge between the two is through a ferrite, capacitor, diode, or short.

Comment: Hmmm, if "splitting" refers to planes, then it still doesn't refer just to the practice of inserting a choke to create an RF-isolated ground net independent of whether it's a plane.  Thanks for describing these terms as you know them though.

Comment: @gwideman The planes can be bridged with different means, but they are all still called splitting the plane as far as I know.

Comment: Again, I appreciate your comments. However, I think you read "plane" into my question where I did not mention it. Regardless, I think we've beaten this terminology sidetrack to death :-)

Comment: @gwideman I suppose I did. A plane is implicit in that.

Comment: You must be a PCB designer who feels if it's not on a PCB with a ground plane, it's not worth building :-).

Comment: More salient to my question, your comment "keep the DC potential of both planes balanced, but prevents high frequency noise return currents from contaminating the planes. But it doesn't work..." suggests that prior practice relied on some vague notion of "contaminated plane", and "balancing the planes"... two rather ill-defined and perhaps poorly thought-out ideas.

Comment: @gwideman Contamination is what I said earlier about ground currents from a noisy part of the circuit flowing in the ground for a sensitive part.  It does keep the planes from being contaminated, sort of, but there are certain return that MUST cross over the divide. For example, a component for one GND sending a signal to a component for the other GND. The return current for that signal MUST find its way back and that divide (on a PCB) and any ferrite along the way will give it a harder time than it needs to and result in more EMI. It will find its way back even if GND are isolated.

Comment: Balancing the planes simply means you don't want the two grounds to be at a different voltage since components use their respective plane as a reference and when they communicate with each other, assume the other component is also using the same reference.

Comment: "Contamination" explanation and "Balancing" explanation: Good discussion for other readers. Yes, I well understand these two lines of reasoning, which are what motivated my question in the first place. It seemed to me that chokes in the ground net would hurt rather than help these goals. And that the practice of including them would thus be based on a mistaken sequence of reasoning such as "we want an analog ground without contamination" and "chokes block contamination", therefore insert choke.. neglecting to look at the specifics of the underlying electrical phenomena.